# std::vector in MyClass ptr causing crash on destructor

Tags: class, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a problem in regards to a custom class I have made. The original intention was to create a particle emitter and in this emitter are two vectors to hold colors and the particles themselves.

The problem exactly is trying to destruct this custom class which functions perfectly if you do not call the destructor, which is obviously bad.

I have reduced this to a very short, compileable example.

Test.h

```
#include <vector>
class Test{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
protected:
    std::vector<int> Ints;
};
```

And the main.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Test* t;
    delete[] t;
    return 0;
}
```

In the Implementation file is just empty constructor and destructors.

Something to note is, this only happens when the "Test" is a pointer, which would preferred to be avoided.

Will provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting something that hasn't allocated a memory and that too in wrong way.

Allocate memory first

```
Test *t = new Test;
```

then,

```
delete t; // Note no []
```

Also, since `C++11` is tagged, prefer using smart pointers, which do the memory management for you on its own

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you. Also, I did have the new keyword in my original program, just forgot it in the example. Can I ask when else to use [] vs no []?

Comment: `delete []` is used to delete arrays of objects, so only if you do `T *p = new T[count]`. Generally best avoided except in implementations of classes - use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @KnightRaven whenever you use `[]` with `new`. The rule is whatever gets allocated with `new []` should be deallocated with corresponding `delete []`, same for only `new` and `delete`. Search on SO you'll get plenty on informations.

Comment: Alright. Thank you both for that. I got into the habit of doing delete[] and this is the first problem I have had using it. I will be more careful in the future. I will also look into smart pointers.

Comment: advising stack storage, or at the very least, a `unique_ptr`  would be much, much safer

Answer (score 1):

If `t` is a pointer then you need to give it something to point to first, as @P0W points out. But why not just declare `t` to be a local (stack) variable?

```
#include "Test.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Test t;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason is because t needs to take variables in its constructor and I don't want to have to use initialized lists because work has to be done before initializing it.

Comment: Perhaps a more complete example of what you're trying to do then? (Your post seemed to indicate that you'd like to avoid pointers.) As pointed out by @P0W, you have to allocate an object before deleting it (if you're allocating it with `new`), and you need to delete it with the correct delete (or use smart pointers, which is generally preferred). But if you delay creating the object until after you have done other set-up, then you can put the object on the stack at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating object Test. You have created an pointer of type Test. For a pointer you need to use the keyword "new".

Test * t = new Test();